# Pug/jade not picking up a variable in Express js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am trying to pass in a variable that checks the hostname and renders a different graphic based on the hostname.

on app.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

  app.use('/', indexRouter);
  app.use('/login', loginRouter);

 app.locals.subdomain = req.hostname;

}
```

in my pug/jade template I want to be able to do something like this.

```
if subdomain == "college.alumni.org"
  div(class="container" style="background-image: url(/images/alumni.png);")
else
  div(class="container" style="background-image: url(/images/admissions.jpg);")
```

Right now is not rendering either graphic.

Comment: Does the `.container` have a height greater than 0? Have you ensured the paths to the images are correct?

Comment: @Sean no, I dont think so. and yes, paths are correct.

Comment: If the container has no height, no background image will appear, because there's no pixels to put a background on.

Comment: If you're setting the variable inside the route handler, it's better to use `res.locals` instead of `app.locals`